# Request failed with error code "ENTITY_ERROR.ATTRIBUTE.INVALID.DUPLICATE"

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, testflight, code-signing-certificate

App record creation failed due to an invalid attribute. Request failed with error code "ENTITY_ERROR.ATTRIBUTE.INVALID.DUPLICATE", and reason "The provided entity includes an attribute with a value that has already been used The Bundle ID you entered has already been used."

I have an app, which uploaded in the AppStore (React Native app). Recently, I recreated project using new version of React Native. App working correctly, I choose bundle id from my uploaded app, [image]but when I uploading my app to TestFlight it gives error (photo).

Comment: Any update? i have the same issue, identifer and sku exists in the apple dev portal but cannot upload to testflight

Answer (score 9):

I faced the same problem.

I reviewed my settings and found that I had the wrong Bundle Identifier. I fixed it and the problem was solved.

Comment: I have a correct bundle id

Comment: Yes, mine had a dash in it, like `com.this-app`. After removing it I could upload. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

The problem for me was, that I only tried to create the app from Xcode. Go to AppStoreConnect, Apps, and create the app manually with the bundle ID you set in your Xcode project.

[image: New App in AppStoreConnect]

After the new app is in your apps, you can restart the "Distribute App" from Xcode.

Answer (score 4):

This happened to me today. I had already created/defined the app in App Store Connect.

The problem was that I'd created the app as one user (the Admin of App Store Connect) but I was trying to upload the app as a separate separate "build" user account on App Store Connect; due to my mistake, the "build" user didn't have access to the app that the Admin had created.

(You can see which account Xcode is using under the Xcode --> Preferences menu, in the Accounts section.)

In a browser, I logged into App Store Connect as my "build" user that Xcode was using, and, sure enough, my app didn't show up, even though the app did appear when I logged in as the Admin of App Store Connect.

I fixed the permissions of my "build" user and then uploading to ASC worked normally.

Comment: Hello. Thanks, but it does not work. I will find different decisions

Comment: Thanks, i had two users and one didn't had access to my app.

Answer (score 1):

Just happened to me some mins ago, this can happen to you if your network is not strong or there is a break in your network.

My app has bee successfully uploaded to App Store connect

Comment: Indeed this a network issue

Answer (score 1):

The language was the problem for me, i had registered my app as English (USA) and was trying to Archive as English (UK), returned to USA and that solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue what fixed it for me was to delete the app identifier file where the app bundle is stored and save a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Try these solutions:

1. Check internet connection
2. Try to upload the app 2-3 times.
3. Check the app bundle identifier, it should be same as in app store bundle id